# Create dynamic class with Angular

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-class, ng-style

I'm trying to add a dynamic class in Angular template and set a style attributes accordingly.

HTML would be -- `<body class="{{ product-id }}">`

CSS would be --
    `product-id : { color: #ccc; }`
Where product-id would be a dynamic value.

What would be the best method to do this? I want to be able to have this be a selector I could use for various element locations within the page which is why ng-style isn't working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach for what you're looking for is the `ng-class` directive which allows you to set different dynamic classes based on $scope variables.

You can check out the docs for `ng-class` [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass).

Hope that helps you out!

Comment: im familiar with ng-class, but how would you then define the style? for ex. product-848483823 would be set to { color: #ccc; } or product-0943094 would also be set to the same style.

Comment: Hmm. How many different style combinations are there? and how would the mapping be defined? or where do the style definitions come from? You could define a mapping object in your controller and pass that into the `ng-class` directive attribute possibly if you have a handle on the different styles. Ideally, your styling will be located in CSS files though.